# How to use Broadcast receiver to Monitor Internet connection during running application

Tags: java, android

hello guys I am currently making a Web Focused crawling

is there any method to watch or monitor the internet connection during the crawling process

if the internet suddenly goes down or dead then there will be an alert for it

thx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BroadCastReceiver` with action `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. System will broadcast this whenever a change in the network connectivity occurs. Here is a complete example for that - [`Android network connectivity BroadcastReceiver`](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/android-network-connectivity-broadcastreceiver/)